# get value of closets select2 jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to get the `closest()` select2 value from where I click the save button `.save_entry`.

I am attempting to get the value of the select with `$(this).closest('select').val();` but it will return undefined. I have tried many variations but because `select2` generates other HTML there seems to be an issue with closest trying to get that value. I have multiple selects on the page so I have to use a class.

How do I get the value of the closest select?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control select2custom" style="width: 100%">'+data+'</select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm save_entry" type="button" data-id="'+row_id+'">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '.save_entry', function() {
    var new_value = $(this).closest('select').val();
})
```

Comment: It's normal, it's not a parent of `.save_entry` (or itself) but a 'brother', you have to use `prev()` instead of `closest()`

Comment: Just discovered that `var new_value = $(this).parent().parent().find('select').val();` gets the value. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @GameTag it's not a brother.  It's the sibling of a parent element.

Comment: @Taplar yep you right, i didn't see the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` searches for parents of the element only. The select element is not a parent of the button. Find the div, then find the child select.

Given your markup, one possible way to do this, would be to find the closest input-group, and then find the nested select2custom element, which is the select.

```
$(this).closest('.input-group').find('.select2custom')
```

Comment: You can also use `$(this).parent().siblings('select').val();`

Comment: Sure, however that relies slightly more on the existing dom structure.  Using closest and find with classes only restricts your markup to being some form of a parent and child relation.  Those elements could move around and it would still work. @Rohit.007

Comment: Yes, but change in CSS class will stop it.

Comment: Sure, both approaches have varying degrees of fragility.  But that's true for all code.  @Rohit.007

Answer (score 0):

Taplar's answer is good, you can also replace your `delegateTarget` (here, the `document`) by the `input-group` class to find more easier the `select` selector.

```js
$('.input-group').on('click', '.save_entry', function(e){
   
   console.log( $(e.delegateTarget).find('select').length )
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control select2custom" style="width: 100%">'+data+'</select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm save_entry" type="button" data-id="'+row_id+'">
            <i class="fas fa-check">Click me</i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

WARNING : When you call this event declaration you have to be sure that `.input-group` markup is present to work.